# Trying to use Cascading Filter in Tableau 2020.3.0 with single select drop-down list. Not able to change the default selection in drop-down filter

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to use Cascading Filter in Tableau 2020.3.0 with single select drop-down list. Not able to change the default selection in dependent drop-down filter.

My scenario:
I have following structure

Pillar 1
... Indicator 1.1
... Indicator 1.2
Pillar 2
... Indicator 2.1
... Indicator 2.2

Then I have some visualization showing indicator level progress. I want to apply cascading filter in a way that user can select Pillar from a single select drop-down list and then select Indicator from second drop-down list showing Only relevant values.

I am able to set both drop-downs and filtering is also working fine. But when I change the Pillar value, I also want to set the default selected value from Indicator drop-down. May the following image helps you under stand my query.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRSsa.png)

In attached image, you can see a value in brackets for Indicator drop-down, that value is the selected value, selected by the user when Pillar 1 was selected, and it is in brackets because it is not relevant according to the current selection in Pillars drop-down. All irrelevant values are gone after changing selection in Pillar drop-down but this irrelevant value is not removed automatically because it is current select value.

I want to get rid of this irrelevant selection and set the default select to X.1 where X represent the selected pillar.

Please help me as this consuming lots of my time at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `create hierarchy` option for desired fields.

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal for your response. I have tried to your suggestion but creating hierarchy not affecting dependent drop down list and the behavior is still the same.

Comment: I don't think you can stop Tableau from keeping the old dropdown value as (<value>) after you change selections.

Comment: @AtherKhan, I successfully tried on sample superstore data.  create `hierarchy` and use an appropriate option for filter.

Comment: I tested in 2020.3 and putting fields into `hierarchy` doesn't change the filtering behaviour described by OP. AnilGoyal, can you please post a demo workbook with your workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your cascadig filter menu and select "Only relevant values" option

[image]

Comment: Exactly.  But the option will show desired results only if hierarchies have been created.

Comment: Actually this is not true... if you try to build 2 filters with Sample - Superstore, based on Segment and Customer Name without any hierachy, selecting Only relevant value for Customer Name filter, you will see that the customer name list reflect your selection for Segment filter